# Make StringIO applicable for IO.foreach

Tags: ruby, string, io, file-descriptor

I would like to make the following lines work:

```
input = StringIO.new
input.write("test\ntest2")
IO.foreach(input) { |line| … }
```

I know that `IO.foreach` takes a file description. Can I turn that into a file descriptor or fake it, make it work in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

To read from a `StringIO` after you've written to it, you need to roll it back to the beginning, using `seek`:

```
input = StringIO.new
input.write("test\ntest2")
input.seek(0)
input.each_line { |x| p x }
# "test\n"
# "test2"
```